# JMockit : How to inject a MockUp class into a tested class?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, dependency-injection, jmockit

I'm new to JMockIt and am trying to figure out/understand how to use `@Injectable` for a top-level MockUp class that I have already defined.

For example:

```
// JUnit Test Class
public class RepositoryTest {

    @Tested private Repository repository;
    @Injectable private ResultsAPIWrapper resultsApiWrapper;

    @Test
    public void testRepo(){
        new ResultsApiWrapper();
        assertThat(repository.doSomething(), is("done" ) );
    }
}


// Class under test
public class Repository{

   @Autowired private ResultsAPIWrapper resultsApiWrapper;

   public String doSomething(){
      return resultsApiWrapper.load();
   }
}

// Mocked implementation of the ResultsAPIWrapper that I want injected into Repository
public class ResultsApiWrapperMock extends MockUp<ResultsAPIWrapper>{
   @Mock
   public String load(){
      return "done";
   }
}
```

If I try the above, I get an error

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Class already mocked: com.fw.wrappers.ResultsAPIWrapper
    at com.fw.wrappers.mock.ResultsApiWrapperMock.<init>(ResultsApiWrapperMock.java:12)
    at com.fw.repository.RepositoryTest.testRepo(RepositoryTest.java:38)
```

But If I remove the `new ResultsApiWrapper()` then I do not know how to specify which is the class I want to use as my mocked implementation for the autowire.

Am I misunderstanding how to do this?  How can I specify that I want JMockit to autowire using my `MockUp<>` implementation?

Answer (score 0):

I'm new too but I think something like this would work in your case...
This will mock the ResultsAPIWrapper() and not initialize any static variables and create a specific mock for load():

```
new MockUp<ResultsAPIWrapper>() {
  @Mock
  void $clinit() {
    //disable static initialization
  }

  @Mock
  public String load() {
     return "done";
  }
};
```

Comment: The one thing I didn't try, but it still does not work.  JMockit still complains that ResultsAPIWrapper is already mocked (due to the @Injectable field).